# How can I put into a 2D array a list of binary string

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary list of string numbers as following:

```
['0b111',
 '0b1110011',
 '0b1110100',
 '0b11101001',
 '0b1100111',
 '0b1100001',
 '0b1101110',
 '0b1101111']
```

And I would like to put this list into a 2D array of integers as following:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

I have first removed the '0b' of the binary sequences and put it in the res list. Then I've created a 2D array in order to put my list into it. And I have tried to do a double loop but I'm a bit confusing with it :

```
 res = []
    for i in range(len(conv_bin)):
        res.append(conv_bin[i][2:])
    arr = np.array(res)
    arr2 = np.zeros((8,8))
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr2.shape[0]):
            arr2[i] = arr[j]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the numpy [unpackbits](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html#numpy.unpackbits) function to help.

```py
import numpy as np
conv_bin = ['0b111',
            '0b1110011',
            '0b1110100',
            '0b11101001',
            '0b1100111',
            '0b1100001',
            '0b1101110',
            '0b1101111']

np.unpackbits(np.array([[int(s,2)] for s in conv_bin], dtype=np.uint8), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for loops you can use this:

```
import numpy as np
conv_bin=['0b111',
 '0b1110011',
 '0b1110100',
 '0b11101001',
 '0b1100111',
 '0b1100001',
 '0b1101110',
 '0b1101111']
res =[]
for string in conv_bin:
    ls=[]
    string=string[2:]
    for ch in string:
        ls.append(ch)
    res.append(ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you can avoid the creation of multiple new lists like res and arr2 as well with the solution I'm writing below.
- A simple solution would be to traverse the binary matrix in reverse order

```
arr2 = np.zeros((8,8))
for i in range(len(conv_bin)):
    '''
    1. zip is function is to loop across two variables in this for loop
    2. j is traversing each binary in the reverse order only until the 2nd index, 
    3. k is used to index the resultant array from reverse (we need different variables since the index values differ)
    '''
    for j,k in zip(range(len(conv_bin[i])-1, 1, -1), range(-1,-9,-1 )):
        arr2[i][k] = conv_bin[i][j]
```

PS - In case you didn't know, in python you can index array from the reverse like this:
arr[-1] -> last element of array
arr[-2] -> last but one element
arr[-3] -> last but two elements and so on

Hope I've been clear in my answer